# SAP WebIDE Trial - OData Service Northwind not available

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I've registered for the SAP HCP trial today.

Now I am working through the first tutorials and steps. I set up the destination for the Northwind OData service with the following parameters.

[image: SAP HCP Destinations]

When I click on Check Conneciton i get following error:

`Failure reason: "Read timed out (local port 44542 to address 10.117.12.62 (vsa1780079.nwtrial.od.sap.biz), remote port 8080 to address 10.117.18.16 (sgw-a1s-03-int.od.sap.biz))"`

Is there a restriction with the trial account or could it be an other issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: Try with your destination pointing to the following URL: http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc

Comment: Changed the destination to your sugested URL and to `...org/V3/...` also. Still the same error message.

Comment: Try changing it to an OData V2 URL. UI5 and the web IDE in general only support OData V1 and 2.

Comment: I still run into the timeout. I also tryed https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/07/sapui5-application-best-practices-with-crud-support-in-sap-web-ide/ which is using OData V2 and get following Message from Firebug `HTTP Status 504 - Socket connection timed out
 for host http://services.odata.org. Reason: Read timed out (local port 41369 to address 10.117.12.250
 (vsa1779957.nwtrial.od.sap.biz), remote port 8080 to address 10.117.18.16 (sgw-a1s-03-int.od.sap.biz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error right now, but it was working some time ago! May be it's a temp issue